# Why this array is coming empty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im doing a fetch on some data at firebase at my firebase app.

I triple check, and debugged the code. The first fetch returns me 5 items on the array. Then I need to get the id of the user and do another fetch to get the data from the user. This is my code:

```
export const fetchStyleItems = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: GET_STYLE_ITEMS_REQUEST });
  database
    .ref("styles_items")
    .orderByChild("posted")
    .once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
      const exists = snapshot.val() !== null;
      if (exists) data = snapshot.val();
      var photo_feed = [];
      for (var photo in data) {
        const photoObj = data[photo];
        database
          .ref("users")
          .child(photoObj.author)
          .once("value")
          .then(function(snapshot) {
            const exists = snapshot.val() !== null;
            if (exists) data = snapshot.val();
            console.log(`inside the lasso ${photoObj} `);
            photo_feed.push({
              id: photo,
              url: photoObj.url,
              caption: photoObj.caption,
              name: photoObj.name,
              price: photoObj.price,
              style_recomendation: photoObj.style_recomendation,
              style_type: photoObj.style_type,
              posted: photoObj.posted,
              author: data.username
            });                   

            });
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      }
      console.log();
      dispatch({
        type: GET_STYLE_ITEMS_SUCCESS,
        payload: photo_feed
      });
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
};
```

The problem. When I debug my code, and try to dispatch the GET_STYLE_ITEMS_SUCCESS the array photo_feed is coming empty.

I think Im missing some scope here. But Im stuck for 3 hours right now and cant see what is wrong.

Comment: you are pushing nothing in photo_feed array. I think your error is there... 1 more thing console log your photoObj

Comment: Muhammad, I just comented the code to dont be very large on the text. But im putting a json inside. Let me edit to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're iterating the array in the for in loop and making async calls, but you're not awaiting those async calls. So photo_feed is empty at the time you want to dispatch the array

specifically, here

```
for (var photo in data) {
        const photoObj = data[photo];
        database
          .ref("users")
          .child(photoObj.author)
          .once("value")
          .then(function(snapshot) {
           // this is async
          })
```

so you should wait for those promises. Furthermore, your function is async but you're using chainable `.then()` methods, instead of await (That's the purpose of adding async). So I rewrote it a bit, and replaced your `var` with `let`

```
export const fetchStyleItems = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: GET_STYLE_ITEMS_REQUEST });
    let snapshot = await database
      .ref("styles_items")
      .orderByChild("posted")
      .once("value");
    const exists = snapshot.val() !== null;
    if (exists) { 
      data = snapshot.val();
    }
    let photo_feed = [];
    for (let photo in data) {
      const photoObj = data[photo];
      let snapshot = await database
        .ref("users")
        .child(photoObj.author)
        .once("value");
      const exists = snapshot.val() !== null;
      if (exists) {
        data = snapshot.val()
      };
      photo_feed.push({
        id: photo,
        url: photoObj.url,
        caption: photoObj.caption,
        name: photoObj.name,
        price: photoObj.price,
        style_recomendation: photoObj.style_recomendation,
        style_type: photoObj.style_type,
        posted: photoObj.posted,
        author: data.username
      });
    }
    dispatch({
      type: GET_STYLE_ITEMS_SUCCESS,
      payload: photo_feed
    });   
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

Further reading about [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

I am not 100% sure await works fine with `for..in` (I believe it does); however if it does not you can replace it with a `for..of` loop plus using `Object.keys(data)`

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is making an async call for each photo in data --> you are not waiting for the call to return before making the next call to get the photo object. You want to get the photo object for the first data item, and then, when that returns, get the photo object for the next photo data item.

This code is causing your problem:

```
for (var photo in data) {
        const photoObj = data[photo];
        database
          .ref("users")
          .child(photoObj.author)
          .once("value")
          .then(function(snapshot) {
            const exists = snapshot.val() !== null;
            if (exists) data = snapshot.val();
            console.log(`inside the lasso ${photoObj} `);
            photo_feed.push({
              id: photo,
              url: photoObj.url,
              caption: photoObj.caption,
              name: photoObj.name,
              price: photoObj.price,
              style_recomendation: photoObj.style_recomendation,
              style_type: photoObj.style_type,
              posted: photoObj.posted,
              author: data.username
            });                   

            });
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the results before dispatching, since they are asynchronous. You can map all the promises to an array and then use [Promise#all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Like

```
const photoFeedPromises = data.map(photoObj => {
  return database
    .ref("users")
    .child(photoObj.author)
    .once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
      const exists = snapshot.val() !== null;
      if (exists) data = snapshot.val();
      console.log(`inside the lasso ${photoObj} `);
      return { snapshot }; // Or whatever you need
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
});

Promise.all(photoFeedPromises).then(results => {
  const photo_feed = results.filter(result => result !== undefined);
  dispatch({
    type: GET_STYLE_ITEMS_SUCCESS,
    payload: photo_feed
  });
});
```

You need to replace the `for` loop and the call to `dispatch` in your code with this snippet I've posted.